Rename a version of a document in Google Docs programmatically
I have a document on Google Docs, for example: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1U_Be02ViQp0UKPYNQo184ks4Vv-ey8mNoawJtTyC1R8
I want to rename a specific version of the document to some name like "Version 1.0 - 20240101".
I want to do it programmatically using Python/JS/... or REST API.
Rename only latest version is also ok.
Please help!
This is code to get all revisions of a document but I want to edit and rename a revision.
Just keep it here to let you start faster.
import os
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
import urllib.request


def get_revision_history(fileId):
    # don't commit your token file to the repo
    KEY_FILE = 'token.json'
    DOWNLOAD_DIR = 'download'
    curDir = os.path.join(DOWNLOAD_DIR, fileId)
    if not os.path.isdir(curDir):
        os.mkdir(curDir)

    # authenticate with the Google APIs using your service account
    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        KEY_FILE,
        scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents',
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
    )

    # initialize the Google Drive API client, only v2 works (not v3)
    drive_service = build('drive', 'v2', credentials=credentials)

    try:
        # get the revision history of the Google Docs
        revisions = drive_service.revisions().list(fileId=fileId).execute()
        print(f"{fileId}: {len(revisions['items'])} revisions found")


    except HttpError as error:
        print(f"An error occurred: {error}")
        raise error
        return None


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # fileId = # it's in the Google Docs link, https://docs.google.com/document/d/fileId/
    fileId = "1U_Be02ViQp0UKPYNQo184ks4Vv-ey8mNoawJtTyC1R8"
    get_revision_history(fileId)

I couldn't find API to rename a version.

From what I know, the feature to rename a specific version of the document to some name is currently not possible with the Google Drive API. Both Service: googleapis.com/drive/v2 and Service: googleapis.com/drive/v3 are able to access version histories. However, they lack the functionality to allow individuals to rename them.

I recommend that you submit a feature request, as that's the best way to tell Google about these kinds of things.

Thank you for your answers.
I submitted a feature request to GG.
